# How does an instance of "Arbitrary" looks for a tree?

Tags: class, haskell, instance, quickcheck

In our CS-Lectures we currently learn about QuickCheck in Haskell. Now I got a task to use QuickCheck with the following tree-type:

```
data Tree = Leaf Int | Node Tree Tree
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I have already written some necessery equations to check different properties of trees.
I know, that I need an instance of "Arbitrary" to run the whole thing.
So tried this:

```
instance Arbitrary Tree where
   arbitrary = sized tree'
     where tree' 0 = do a <- arbitrary
                        oneof [return (Leaf a)]
           tree' n = do a <- arbitrary
                        oneof [return (Leaf a), return (Node (tree' (n-1)) (tree' (n-1)))]
```

But now I am getting some errors such as:

```
Couldn't match type `Gen Tree' with `Tree'
      Expected type: a -> Tree
        Actual type: a -> Gen Tree
    * In an equation for `arbitrary':
          arbitrary
            = sized tree'
            where
                tree' 0
                  = do a <- arbitrary
                       ....
                tree' n
                  = do a <- arbitrary
                       ....
      In the instance declaration for `Arbitrary Tree'
   |
61 |      where tree' 0 = do a <- arbitrary
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

or:

```
    * Couldn't match type `Tree' with `Gen Tree'
      Expected type: Int -> Gen Tree
        Actual type: Int -> Tree
    * In the first argument of `sized', namely tree'
      In the expression: sized tree'
      In an equation for `arbitrary':
          arbitrary
            = sized tree'
            where
                tree' 0
                  = do a <- arbitrary
                       ....
                tree' n
                  = do a <- arbitrary
                       ....
   |
60 |    arbitrary = sized tree'
   |                      ^^^^^
```

I think the problem is that I am doing some kind of recursion when choosing a Node. Because in that case the subtrees of that node are not trees but more like "return trees". Hopefully you know, what I mean.

Can somebody help me with this?

Thank you :)

Comment: What is `sized` here? It is not clear to me why you need to know the size in advance.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `sized` is provided by `QuickCheck`. It is important for tree-like data structures because of how easy it is to define a distribution with infinite expected size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to implement this is with:

```
instance Arbitrary Tree where
   arbitrary = frequency [
       (3, Leaf <$> arbitrary)
     , (1, Node <$> arbitrary <*> arbitrary)
     ]
```

Here the **`arbitrary`** functions in bold are the ones implement for the `Tree` instance. The arbitrary for `Leaf` is the `arbitrary` instance for an `Int`.

Here we thus specify that an arbitrary tree is a leaf with an arbitrary `Int`, or it is a `Node` with an arbitrary left and right sub-`Tree`.

or with [`sized :: (Int -> Gen a) -> Gen a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:sized):

```
instance Arbitrary Tree where
   arbitrary = sized go
        where go 0 = Leaf <$> arbitrary
              go n = oneof [Leaf <$> arbitrary, Node <$> go' <*> go']
                  where go' = go (n-1)
```

here the size specifies the depth of the tree, not the number of elements.

Comment: This distribution has infinite expected size. Calling the expected number of `Leaf`s produced by `arbitrary` *x*, we have the equation *x = (1/2)*1 + (1/2)*(x + x) = 1/2 + x*, which has no finite solution.

Comment: @DanielWagner: ah yes, by altering the weights, normally the expected size should be two now, since `x = 3/4 + (1+2*x)/4` for the number of "data constructors", or 3/2 for the number of items.

Answer (score 0):

This can be derived using the [*generic-random*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-random-1.5.0.1/docs/Generic-Random-DerivingVia.html) library

```
{-# Language DataKinds     #-}
{-# Language DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# Language DerivingVia   #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Generic.Random.DerivingVia
import Test.QuickCheck

-- ghci> :set -XTypeApplications
-- ghci> sample @Tree arbitrary
-- Node (Leaf 0) (Node (Leaf 0) (Node (Leaf 0) (Node (Node (Leaf 0) (Leaf 0)) (Leaf 0))))
-- Leaf 0
-- Leaf (-2)
-- Leaf 5
-- Leaf 0
-- Leaf 2
-- Leaf 1
-- Leaf 7
-- Node (Leaf (-7)) (Leaf (-2))
-- Node (Leaf 4) (Node (Leaf 0) (Leaf 3))
-- Node (Leaf 5) (Leaf (-2))
data Tree = Leaf Int | Node Tree Tree
  deriving
  stock (Eq, Show, Generic)

  deriving Arbitrary
  via GenericArbitraryRec '[2, 1] Tree
```

Let me know if there is something wrong with the distribution!